# Data sharing between sibling components in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, components, angular2-services

I am working on Angular 2 application in which I have two components inside a module. Both modules are independant and have no parent-child relationship. First component collects some data from user which is required to be passed to second component.

**Component I:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user-otp-generation',
    templateUrl: `../partials/user-management/user-generate-otp.html`,
    moduleId: module.id,
    // providers: [UserService]
})

export class UserOtpGenerationComponent{
constructor(private UserService: UserService) { }

user: User = new User();

onSubmit(){
    this.UserService.generateOTP(this.user.phone)
        .then(response => {
                this.UserService.setUserProperty('phone', this.user.phone); //From user input
                this.UserService.setUserProperty('otp', response.otp);  //From API response
            })
    }
}
```

**Component II:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user-authentication',
    templateUrl: `../partials/user-management/user-authentication.html`,
    moduleId: module.id,
    // providers: [UserService]
})

export class UserAuthenticationComponent {
    constructor(private UserService: UserService) {
        this.user = UserService.getUser();
    }

    user:User;

    onSubmit(){
        this.UserService.verifyOTP(this.user.otp)
            .then(response => { //Do something  })
    }
}
```

Since both components are at sibling level, I think using data sharing service is a good approach. So, I created the data service `UserService`. Also, `User` is just a model class which has many fields corresponding to a user instance.

**User class**

```
export class User {
    phone: string;
    otp: string;
    reference_id: string;
    // Many other similar fields
}
```

**UserService**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private user: User = new User();

    getUser(){
        return this.user;
    }

    setUserProperty(key, value){
        this.user[key] = value;
    }

    generateOTP(phone: string): Promise<any>{
        return this.http.get('some-url').toPromise();
    }
}
```

There is no parent component. These components are inside a user module which has routes as follows:

```
const userRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'generate-otp', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'generate-otp', component: UserOtpGenerationComponent},
    {path: 'authenticate', component: UserAuthenticationComponent}
]
```

I added a `user` property at service level. Inside component I, I created a `user` property whose value is finaly used to modify the service `user` property so that it is accessible in component II. During component II instantiation, I initialize its user property with the service user property. But, I get empty object as user this time.
I have registered service as `providers: [UserService]` in NgModule of user.module. The same issue occurs if I register it at both component's level. What is the issue?

Comment: Seems like UserService is getting instantiated twice; once for each component. I need it to get instantiated only once so that data can be shared among components.

Comment: please post the `user.module` and your `app.module`. Also, add a constructor to the service and in that add a log statement to be certain it was instantiated more than once.

Comment: I hv created a plnkr at https://embed.plnkr.co/FQGDe1gbSI5speWFLDLl/. This is working but same code is not working in my local machine. I have used Angular quickstart seed (https://github.com/angular/quickstart) and added my code. It is not working. However, interestingly it is again working if I use Angular CLI and add my code. Any reasons?

Comment: Seems like your code is fine and works as expected in a fresh angular-cli project and a fresh angular quickstart. There might be something different in your old source code causing it. But at least you know how to fix it.

Comment: This seems funny. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: Hi Aosis. We prefer answers here (see the posting box below) rather than [solved] devices in titles. Would you be able to summarise how you fixed it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a proper answer for this issue. However, as evident from the above comments, the code works fine when I try it in a plunker or I use Angular CLI 1.0.2. Earlier, I was using quickstart seed. 
As suggested by @Ahmed Musallam, I used console.log statements inside service and of course, service was being instantiated twice.
I am now using `angular-cli`. This is the only solution I could figure out.